# Konva line polygon within another line polygon detection

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I use React Konva and want to know if a Konva line polygon is completely within another line polygon, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond simple rectangles, shape collision detection is not simple and though Konva does have some overlap detection, testing for one shape inside another is not provided by Konva AFAIK.

Libs are available, and you can read up on the subject at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection